# 7zip Multi-Part Archives on Linux: E_FAIL

Tags: ubuntu, multipart, 7zip

I have an Ubuntu server and just spend 2 days transferring a 22GB multi-part archive to it. The 22GB is divided in 1800 10MB parts.

Whenever I try to extract them (p7zip 9.20):

```
7z x "*.7z.*"
```

I get an error:

```
Error: E_FAIL
```

And yes, I have checked and I have more than 250GB free disk space, so that is not causing the problem. The OS is 64bit and the disk is formatted with ext4.

Does anyone know why this error is caused or any other program besides p7zip that I can use to extract them?

Answer (score 2):

For all the souls who have the same problem: concatenate the parts manually and then extract.

```
ls -v | grep .7z | sed 's| |\\ |g' | xargs cat > out.7z
```

1. ls -v: sort the files numerically.
2. grep: only select 7zip archives
3. sed: handle spaces in file names
4. cat: concatenate the files.

And then simply:

```
7z x out.7z
```